# Python loop and digits

Tags: python, loops, max

I would need help to write a program that will load the 5 three-digit numbers.

The program should then print a number that has the highest digit of
hundreds, tens and ones.

Here is my code:

```
max_num = 0
for number in range(1,6):
  a = int(input("Enter five three-digit number: "))
  s = a//100
  d = (a//10)%10
  j = a%10
  if(s and d and j) > max_num:
    max_num = a
print(max_num)
```

It only prints the first number.

Comment: How are you storing `5 three digit numbers` in a single variable `a` ?

Comment: "The program should then print a number" - is it looking for one number, or three?

Comment: It should print just the highest

Comment: Did the task come with an example?  I interpret it as wanting a number that has the highest 100s digits of the three, the highest 10s digit of the three, and the highest 1s digit of the three.  Example: input 129, 555, 832; output 858.  For this, the numbers should be left as strings of digits and not converted to ints.  But maybe check with the task giver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the maximum of each digit:

```
s = d = j = 0
for _ in range(5):
    a = int(input("Enter a three-digit number: "))
    s = max(s, a//100)
    d = max(d, (a//10)%10)
    j = max(j, a%10)
print(s*100+d*10+j)
```

But you might find it easier to keep them as strings and manipulate individual characters.